# running a web application through tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, logging

I am trying to run my web application through tomcat server(v7.0.32).The project is developed under eclipse-Juno. when i type "http://localhost:8080/MyNewApp1" in my browser it says, 
**HTTP Status 404 - /MyNewApp1/
type Status report
message /MyNewApp1/
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.32**  when i try to view the log through command line using less **catalina.out** , i get trace as below:

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib
/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/../lib/i
386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 851 ms
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/MyNewApp1.xml
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/docs
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/ROOT
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/examples
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/host-manager
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/manager
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 7, 2012 3:40:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1254 ms
```

Where am i going wrong?I have checked my web.xml file, ensured that it is a web project,i am able to export it as a WAR file and everything seems to be fine for me...But still i get this error and not able to move forward.Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an index.html or index.jsp file at the root of your webapp?

Comment: if your .war file deployed to /home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/ ?  i'd also check the localhost-XXXX logs for startup errors.

Comment: do you mean the one under tomcat?if so i have index.jsp at "/home/kruthi/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/ROOT" where my tomcat is installed.

Comment: Where is your WAR file (or exploded WAR directory) located? Do you have a Tomcat deployment descriptor (context.xml)? Where is it and what does it contain?

Comment: i was wrong in my context file...thank you all for your time! I could resolve it.